# Postgres: Where value equal decimal value

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table looks like this:

[image: source table for query]

When the `WHERE` clause is equal to value with decimal point I get no valid output like:

```
SELECT transponder_id 
FROM signals.dvbs_transponders t 
WHERE t.freq = 11487.77
```

Output: transponder_id = None

When the query is for integer value, query works correctly:

```
SELECT transponder_id 
FROM signals.dvbs_transponders t 
WHERE t.freq = 11470
```

Output: transponder_id = 1009

Also using `BETWEEN` query returns expected values

```
SELECT transponder_id 
FROM signals.dvbs_transponders t 
WHERE t.freq between 11487 and 11488
```

Output: transponder_id = 1010

Why is my query using 'equal' operator not working with decimal values? I don't like the `between` solution as it require to set tolerance range. How the query should be defined to work also with decimal values?

Comment: `freq` isn't a `decimal`, it is a `real`. From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html): "Comparing two floating-point values for equality might not always work as expected."

Comment: Change the datatype to decimal.

Comment: Mandatory read: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it under single quotes :

```
select *
from dvbs_transponders
where freq = '11487.77'
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=86120b0f2e8b0f001c9950107085cd38)